# Cannot uniquely indentify operation

Tags: web-services, jboss5.x

I have a JBoss 5.1 Web Service with two operations
Both operations take the same same request type
Each has it's own action
The web service compile and deploy fine, but when I try and submit a request with soapUI I get the following error:
Cannot uniquely indentify operation: {https://garygateway.quinn.co.za/services/garygateway}GaryRequest

Here is my WSDL

```
<definitions name='GaryGatewayService' targetNamespace='https://garygateway.mediswitch.co.za/services/garygateway' xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' xmlns:ns1='https://garygateway.quinn.co.za/services/garygateway' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' xmlns:tns='https://garygateway.mediswitch.co.za/services/garygateway' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
 <types>
  <xs:schema targetNamespace='https://garygateway.quinn.co.za/services/garygateway' version='1.0' xmlns:ns1='https://garygateway.mediswitch.co.za/services/garygateway' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
   <xs:import namespace='https://garygateway.mediswitch.co.za/services/garygateway'/>
   <xs:element name='GaryRequest' nillable='true' type='ns1:garyRequest'/>
   <xs:element name='GaryResponse' nillable='true' type='ns1:garyResponse'/>
  </xs:schema>
  <xs:schema targetNamespace='https://garygateway.mediswitch.co.za/services/garygateway' version='1.0' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
   <xs:complexType name='garyRequest'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='id' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='name' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='surname' type='xs:string'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='garyResponse'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='message' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='status' type='xs:string'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:schema>
 </types>
 <message name='GaryGatewayEndpoint_requestOneResponse'>
  <part element='ns1:GaryResponse' name='GaryResponse'></part>
 </message>
 <message name='GaryGatewayEndpoint_requestTwoResponse'>
  <part element='ns1:GaryResponse' name='GaryResponse'></part>
 </message>
 <message name='GaryGatewayEndpoint_requestTwo'>
  <part element='ns1:GaryRequest' name='requestTwo'></part>
 </message>
 <message name='GaryGatewayEndpoint_requestOne'>
  <part element='ns1:GaryRequest' name='requestOne'></part>
 </message>
 <portType name='GaryGatewayEndpoint'>
  <operation name='requestOne' parameterOrder='requestOne'>
   <input message='tns:GaryGatewayEndpoint_requestOne'></input>
   <output message='tns:GaryGatewayEndpoint_requestOneResponse'></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name='requestTwo' parameterOrder='requestTwo'>
   <input message='tns:GaryGatewayEndpoint_requestTwo'></input>
   <output message='tns:GaryGatewayEndpoint_requestTwoResponse'></output>
  </operation>
 </portType>
 <binding name='GaryGatewayEndpointBinding' type='tns:GaryGatewayEndpoint'>
  <soap:binding style='document' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>
  <operation name='requestOne'>
   <soap:operation soapAction='https://garygateway.quinn.co.za/services/garygateway/requestOne'/>
   <input>
    <soap:body use='literal'/>
   </input>
   <output>
    <soap:body use='literal'/>
   </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name='requestTwo'>
   <soap:operation soapAction='https://garygateway.quinn.co.za/services/garygateway/requestTwo'/>
   <input>
    <soap:body use='literal'/>
   </input>
   <output>
    <soap:body use='literal'/>
   </output>
  </operation>
 </binding>
 <service name='GaryGatewayService'>
  <port binding='tns:GaryGatewayEndpointBinding' name='GaryGatewayEndpointPort'>
   <soap:address location='http://gary-desktop:8480/wsgateway/GaryGateway'/>
  </port>
 </service>
</definitions>
```

I enabled WS-A addressing which makes the Soap message header look like this:

```
<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:Action>https://garygateway.mediswitch.co.za/services/garygateway/GaryGatewayEndpoint/requestOneRequest</wsa:Action></soapenv:Header>
```

Here are the headers also generated by SoapU:

```
POST /wsgateway/GaryGateway HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "https://garygateway.quinn.co.za/services/garygateway/GaryGatewayEndpoint/requestOneRequest"
Content-Length: 544
Host: gary-desktop:8480
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

But still I am getting the **Cannot uniquely indentify operation** error

Here is the full response:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault>
         <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Cannot uniquely indentify operation: {https://garygateway.quinn.co.za/services/garygateway}GaryRequest</faultstring>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to enable addressing on the web service

```
@WebService(name = "", targetNamespace = "")
@Addressing(enabled = true, required = true)
```